# Collision detection not working on all sides of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

This code is used to test my collisions but it only works on 2 sides on each UIImageView. Why doesn't it work for 3 sides? It'll never work on top side and bottom side of UIImageView or left and right. It only works top and left or top and right or bottom and right or bottom and left. Why is that? How do i make it work on at least 3 sides?

```
int moveX;

int moveY;

viewController.h{

IBOutlet UIImageView *circle;

NSTimer *time;

IBOutlet UIImageView *platform;

}

-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender;
-(void)moveCircle;

-(void)bounce;

@end

viewcontroller.m

-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender{
    start.hidden=YES;

    time=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(moveCircle) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    circleX=arc4random()%11;
    circleX=circleX-5;         

    circleY=arc4random()%11;
    circleY=circleY-5;

    circleX=arc4random()%11;
    circleX=circleX+5;

    circleY=arc4random()%11;;
    circleY=circleY+5;

    if (circleX==0) {
        circleX=1;
    }
    if (circleY==0) {
        circleY=1;
    }

-(void)moveCircle{

    circle.center=CGPointMake(circle.center.x -circleX, circle.center.y -circleY);


    if (circle.center.x <30) {   
        circleX=0-circleX;
    }
    if (circle.center.x >320) {
        circleX=0-circleX;
    }
    if (circle.center.y <28 ) {
        circleY=0-circleY;
    }
    if (circle.center.y >568) {
        circleY=0-circleY;
    }

 [self bounce];  


}

 -(void)bounce{

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(circle.frame, platform.frame)) {

            circleY=arc4random()%5;  
            circleY=0+circleY;      

            circleX=arc4random()%5;
            circleX=0+circleX;   

            circleY=arc4random()%5;
            circleY=0-circleY;        

            circleX=arc4random()%5;
            circleX=0-circleX;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no sense at all in your question but let's look at your code:

Assuming you start with `StartGame` which hopefully happens only once:

- You create a timer (this should be invalidated when the game ends but no matter at the moment)
- you set `circleX` and `circleY` to some random position between -5 and 5
- you set `circleX` and `circleY` to some random position between 5 and 15 (again?!)
- you check if `circleX` and `circleY` are at 0 and set them to 1 (this is highly unlikely to happen due to the previous statement)

Then move circle:

- you add to the circle center the `circleX` and `circleY` values where then I assume those 2 values are actually speed. (so far so good)
- you check the circle position to be out of borders and negate appropriate speed. (This hardcoded values are a bit strange but ok for now I guess)
- You call `bounce`

And the bounce method:

- You check if `circle` and `platform` frames intersect. (O.K. I guess)
- You set a random speed to `circleX` and `circleY` from 0 to 4
- You set a random speed to `circleX` and `circleY` from 0 to -4 (again?!)

So what I can assume from this code is you have 2 views on your view controller where one is a static obstacle called `platform` and the other is a moving `circle`. The circle itself will be moving to some direction depending on some random values from the `StarGame` method and correctly bouncing off the hardcoded borders. If the `circle` intersects with the `platform` the circle will change speed to some random negative values from -4 to 0 in both X and Y.

So what is the issue here exactly? The bouncing off the `platform` will make the `circle` move toward your top-left corner of the screen no matter which side does the `circle` hit the `platform` from. Maybe you need some `if` statements in your `bounce` method to find a correct value for the new speed depending on which side is the `platform` hit from.